# Backpropagate multiple hidden layers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, train, backpropagation

I have created a feed forward neural network using the sigmoid activation function and backpropagation. I was wondering if I would be able to use backpropagation the same way for two hidden layers as I would for one hidden layer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use the same approach to backpropagating neural networks with more than one hidden layers.

Comment: But would that approach be? What is the formula for the 2nd layer?